# Missing information in scraped web data, Google translate, Using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I want to scrape the Google translate website and get the translated text from it using Python 3.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import Request as uReq
from urllib.request import urlopen as open


my_url = "https://translate.google.com/#en/es/I%20am%20Animikh%20Aich"

req = uReq(my_url, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
uClient = open(req)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
html = soup(page_html, 'html5lib')
print(html)
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to find the required information in the parsed Webpage.
In chrome "Inspect", It is showing that the translated text is inside:

```
 <span id="result_box" class="short_text" lang="es"><span class="">Yo soy Animikh Aich</span></span>
```

However, When I am searching for the information in the parsed HTML code, this is what I'm finding in it:

```
<span class="short_text" id="result_box"></span>
```

I have tried parsing using all of html5lib, lxml, html.parser. I have not been able to find a solution for this.
Please help me with the issue.

Comment: you can consider taking a look at this tool or contribute to the project since you share the same goal: https://github.com/nidhaloff/deep_translator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below to get the desired content:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://translate.google.com/#en/es/I%20am%20Animikh%20Aich")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html5lib')
item = soup.select_one("#result_box span").text
print(item)
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
Yo soy Animikh Aich
```

Comment: Yes, I myself got it working. Thank you!
I used PhantomJS because i wanted it to work in the background.

Answer (score 2):

you could use a specific python api:

```
import goslate
gs = goslate.Goslate()
print(gs.translate('I am Animikh Aich', 'es'))
Yo soy Animikh Aich
```

Comment: Actually, I do not want to use any API. This is more like a personal Project. I want to explore web scraping and thus had this idea. If you can suggest a solution, please share.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is modifying the HTML code after it loads. `urllib` can't handle JavaScript, you'll have to use `Selenium` to get the data that you want.

For installation and demo, [refer this link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).